# Second node.js can't connect to mysql in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

At the moment, I'm trying to set up my docker-compose file to run multiple (two) Node.js API's.
The first Node.js server connects fine to the database.

The second Node.js server keeps throwing this error
`original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.29.0.3:3307`

So my question is how to run multiple Node.js API's in docker?

This is my *docker-compose.yaml*:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  ISAAC-floor-database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: isaac
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  ISAAC-sensor-database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: isaac
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    volumes:
      - ./sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  ISAAC-floor-back-end:
    image: jjuless/isaac-floor-back-end
    environment:
      DB_HOST: ISAAC-floor-database
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: isaac
      DB_DATABASE: isaac
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_DIALECT: mysql
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - ISAAC-floor-database

  ISAAC-sensor-back-end:
    image: jjuless/isaac-sensor-back-end
    environment:
      DB_HOST: ISAAC-sensor-database
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: isaac
      DB_DATABASE: isaac
      DB_PORT: 3307
      DB_DIALECT: mysql
    ports:
      - "3001:80"
    depends_on:
      - ISAAC-sensor-database
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql is always listening on port `3306` in each container, so if you want to have multiple mysql instances in the same host, you will need to map **different host ports** to the **same guest port**

Hence you will need to change your `docker-compose` file as follows

```
ISAAC-floor-database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: isaac
    ports:
      - "3306:3306" # <-- HOST port same as GUEST port
    volumes:
      - ./sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

ISAAC-sensor-database:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: isaac
    ports:
      - "3307:3306" # <-- Notice here the GUEST port is the same as the first container!
    volumes:
      - ./sql-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem, still the second API can't connect to the database. Any more ideas?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the second mysql instance from the host? What kind of error do you get within the second API container? A connection refused?

Comment: This is the error I get for the second API connection.

original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:3307
isaac-main-ISAAC-sensor-back-end-1  |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
isaac-main-ISAAC-sensor-back-end-1  |     errno: -111,
isaac-main-ISAAC-sensor-back-end-1  |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
isaac-main-ISAAC-sensor-back-end-1  |     syscall: 'connect',
isaac-main-ISAAC-sensor-back-end-1  |     address: '172.19.0.2',
isaac-main-ISAAC-sensor-back-end-1  |     port: 3307,
isaac-main-ISAAC-sensor-back-end-1  |     fatal: true
}

Comment: Fixed it with setting the DB_PORT to 3306 in the environments in the second API!

Comment: Awesome! I think that the reason it worked is because when you use the docker's hostname of the mysql server ( `ISAAC-sensor-database` ) you don't need to specify any port-mapping, the API container will directly connect to the port of the DB container